# Always wrap UI changes into main thread preventively?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, swift2, grand-central-dispatch

UI changes should be made on the main thread. If not, it can lead to wrong behavior, warnings or crashes (and sometimes it still works like expected though).

Anyway, I've started to wrap almost any UI changes in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue)) { ... }`. Recently I just wondered whether this could be best practice to do so with all UI related stuff, so every single `presentViewController`, `dismissViewController` etc., because the code gets just overflowed by hundreds of those wraps.

Of course, sometimes it is obvious that it wouldn't be needed; e.g. when a user has tapped a button that leads to some immediate UI changes. But there are methods that get called in different contexts, where you should probably ensure it by just wrap it preventively. In the end I've started implementing those everywhere because otherwise you have to be really careful not to misjudge or forget one where needed.

What is your approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should explicitly call UI changes on the main thread each time, but **only if necessary**.

*Rationale*: you only need to specify the main thread if you are not already on the main thread. For example, in a `UIViewController` subclass where you implement methods like `viewDidLoad`, or table view `datasource` methods, you can assume that you are on the main thread already. Thus, to wrap UI statements here into additional `async` blocks is redundant and produces cluttered and unnecessarily verbose code.

If, on the other hand, you are in some background thread, you should make it explicit that you are doing something on the main thread. This will add clarity and enhance readability and maintainability.

Comment: The thing is I'm using a quite dividing architecture (VIPER), so while there might be methods that are clearly called on the main thread anyway there are several that could be called from either main or background or - in other words - I'd have to follow back the whole tree to be sure as one task might be divided and processed through 4 classes (UI, logic, requesting data, ...). What would you suggest for such scenarios (probably a disadvantage of this architecture that you don't see the "big picture" easily everywhere)?

Comment: I would avoid any architecture where it is not clear on which thread something is called. VIPER has many problems, this is one of them. In principle, in VIPER **only** the *Presenter* should call the UI thread.

Comment: I've already build a huge project with VIPER by now - actually I'm quite happy with it despite some minor disadvantages. I'm calling the UI only from the _Presenter_ but e.g. `foundUsers` (to update to UI) which follows some task from the _Interactor_ could be called either from a background thread/query or on the main thread within _Interactor_, right? I updated my code now and actually just left the wraps where explicitly needed and where unsure like especially in all those _Interactor's_ calls in the _Presenter_ after finished tasks. Or do I mix something up in that discussion?

Comment: I think the *Interactor* has no business touching the UI. It should message the *Presenter* to do so. It's cumbersome, but that is the trouble with VIPER in general.

Comment: I got that and I'm doing so. Probably there is something else I haven't understood yet so correct me if I'm wrong: Even though only the presenter is touching the UI, it is not guaranteed it is doing so on main thread always, no? Or why should every call of the _Presenter_, probably from an _Interactor's_ background task automatically ensure the main thread when the _Presenter_ starts updating the UI?